# Erro ao chamar a tela do formulário

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou com problema ao carregar um menu através de outra tela segue o meu código abaixo. Qual seria uma possível solução, para tal erro?

```
public partial class frmMenu : Form
{
    public frmMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void guichesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmCadastroGuiche frm = new frmCadastroGuiche();
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Tela que deveria ser carregada ao clicar no botão do guiche.

```
public partial class frmCadastroGuiche : Form
{
    public frmCadastroGuiche()
    {
        carregarCombos();
        carregando = true;
        carregargrid();
        carregando = false;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    bool pularFiltro = false;
    bool carregando = false;
    public bool setDatabase(Sele.Classes.clsDatabase oDB)
    {
        try
        {
            oAtende.oDB = oDB;
            carregarCombos();
            carregando = true;
            carregargrid();
            carregando = false;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    DataTable dtGuiche = new DataTable();
    public void carregarCombos()
    {
        lstTipoSenha_id.DataSource = oAtende.dtTipoSenha;
        oAtende.dtTipoSenha = oAtende.getSenhaTipo();
        lstTipoSenha_id.DisplayMember = "Tipo da Senha";
        lstTipoSenha_id.ValueMember = "id";
        lstTipoSenha_id.DataSource = oAtende.dtTipoSenha;
    }    
    private void carregargrid()
    {
        carregando = true;
        dg.CurrentCell = null;
        dg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        dtGuiche = oAtende.getGuiches("");
        dg.DataSource = dtGuiche.DefaultView;

        dg.CurrentCell = null;

        dg.ClearSelection();
        carregando = false;
    }
}
```

abaixo disto teria o códigos dos botões de salvar e excluir nos campos que foram passados, mas não coloquei pois não achei necessário creio que o erro não esteja lá.

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: Essa tela frmMenu eu consigo carregar a tela frmRelatórios(não coloquei o código), mas quando tento chamar a tela frmCadastroGuiche atravez do botão não acontece nada, o compilador não informa nenhum erro.

Answer (score 2):

Tá acontecendo alguma exceção e você não está vendo.

O método `InitializeComponents()` precisa ser chamado antes de qualquer interação com os componentes da tela, **porque é este método que cria-os**.

O construtor deveria estar assim

```
public frmCadastroGuiche()
{        
    InitializeComponent();
    carregarCombos();
    carregando = true;
    carregargrid();
    carregando = false;
}
```

Comment: Fiz essa alteração mas ainda o erro persiste, o botão não chama o frmCadastroGuiche, criei até outro botão para o teste e o erro ainda continua

Comment: Cara, é algum erro nos métodos `carregarCombos()` e/ou `carregarGrid()`. Vai removendo eles e testando.

Comment: Criei um terceiro botão e ele agora está chamando a tela, mas ele da essa exceção.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Não é possível ligar ao novo membro de exibição.

justo no método  public void carregarCombos()

Comment: Bem, você já sabe qual o erro e qual o motivo. Boa sorte =D

Comment: Como o próprio @jbueno apontou, o construtor sendo ajustado e só ir comentando os métodos e ver onde está o erro.